# A more elegant version of this function?

Tags: functions, arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

I challenged myself.

The goal was to find a function $f$ with two variables $x$ and $y$ real, which results $1$ if $x=y$ and results $0$ if $x ≠ y$.
But, the fonction can only use additions, soustractions, multiplications, divisions, exponents and roots.

My solution is : $f(x,y) =1 - \sqrt{  \frac{ \sqrt{ (x-y)^{2} }  }  { x-y+0^{(x-y)^{2}} }  ^{2}}$

And my question is : is there a solution more elegant using the same restrictions ?

**EDIT :** I suppose $0^0 = 1$

Comment: 0^0 is not defined so your function is not defined for x=y.

Comment: I assume that $0^0 = 1$

Comment: It's not though. Also, since x and y always appear in the same combination (x-y) you can write this as a function of one variable f(z=x-y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $0^0=1$, then just use:

$$f(x, y)=0^{(x-y)^2}$$

Comment: Surely also $0^{(x-y)}$ also works?

Comment: No because $0^(-1)$ is dangerous.

Comment: @Jack I feel very stupid right now. Thank you ! It's way better.

Comment: @Dan I assume $0^0 = 1$ but $0^x = 0$ as $x ≠ 0$.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry.